# SQL Query to combine alterative rows into a single table using Django's Models

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I have created an attendance server that allows staffs to log their attendance.
There is a manual and a automatic way of logging attendance. The SQL tables for the system is as follows.

| Staff | Local User | Device | Biometrics Log | Punch Log |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Id | Id | Id | Id | Id |
| Name | Name | Location | Local User ID | Staff ID |
|  | Device ID | API Key | Punched On | Punched On |
|  | Staff ID |  |  | Is Disabled |

Anytime a biometrics log is added, if the local user in that log has a staff foreign key then a punch log gets created. I felt that this helps in combining automatic and manual logs. **Manual Logs are added straight to Punch Log**

When the user is requesting for Attendance. This currently will take alterative rows of **punch log** that are active and combines it into a single row.

#### Output Data Format

| Attendance Log |
| --- |
| Id |
| Punch In |
| Punch Out |
| Staff ID |

### CODE IN USE

Currently I am using raw sql query to get the data

The basic logic is to

- Split into two sub queries -> Punch In & Punch Out with Roll Number Unique to User
- Join with Roll Number

```sql
    select i.id, username, i.punched_on as punch_in,  min(punch_out) as punch_out
    from (select *,row_number() over (partition by user_id order by user_id) as r_index from attendance_punch_log) as i
    left join local_user on i.user_id = local_user.id
    left join (
    select  o.logged_on as punch_out, username as out_user
    from (select *, row_number() over (partition by user_id order by user_id) as l_index from attendance_punch_log) as o
    left join local_user on o.user_id = local_user.id) as o on username = out_user and punch_out > punch_in
    where mod(r_index, 2) = 1
    group by username , r_index
    order by punch_in, punch_out
```

### The Django models are as follows

```py
class BiometricsDevice(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(
        Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="device"
    )
    description = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    api_key = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    last_sync = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    sync_user = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    created_on = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="created_biometrics",
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.location.name} - {self.api_key}"


class LocalUser(models.Model):
    ref = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    device = models.ForeignKey(
        BiometricsDevice, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="users"
    )
    # Signal on staff update -> Re-Run Biometrics Log to Punch Log Conversion
    staff = models.ForeignKey(
        Staff,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="biometric_user",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} - {self.device}"

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (["name", "device"], ["name", "ref", "device"])


class PunchLog(models.Model):
    staff = models.ForeignKey(
        Staff,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="punch_log",
    )
    punched_on = models.DateTimeField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    created_on = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="created_punch_logs",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.staff.name} - {self.punched_on}"


class BiometricsLog(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        LocalUser,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="biometrics_log",
    )
    punched_on = models.DateTimeField()

    punch_log = models.OneToOneField(
        PunchLog,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="biometrics_log",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["user", "punched_on"]

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.name} - {self.punched_on}"
```

### The Code to create queryset is as follows

```py
    def get(self, request):
        punch_in = (
            BiometricsLog.objects.annotate(
                index=Window(
                    expression=RowNumber(),
                    order_by=F("user_id").asc(),
                    partition_by=[F("user_id")],
                ),
            )
            .annotate(evenindex=F("index") % 2)
            .filter(evenindex=1)
            .order_by("-punched_on")
        )
        punch_out = (
            BiometricsLog.objects.annotate(
                index=Window(
                    expression=RowNumber(),
                    order_by=F("user_id").asc(),
                    partition_by=[F("user_id")],
                ),
            )
            .annotate(evenindex=F("index") % 2)
            .filter(evenindex=0)
            .order_by("-punched_on")
        )
        # Odd Even index join

        queryset = punch_in.annotate(
            punch_in=F("punched_on"),
            punch_out=Subquery(
                punch_out.filter(
                    index__gt=OuterRef("index"),
                    user_id=OuterRef("user_id"),
                ).values("punched_on")[:1]
            ),
            staff=F("user__staff"),
        )
```

### Final Thoughts

- What other method should i be using to create attendance table in the end ?
- Is it better to create a new table insted of a querset ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the method of determining "in" or "out" in the punch log is overly complicated. This certainly has maintenance issues and could also affect performance.

You could simply add a `direction` field (or even just a boolean) to your punch log model. It would make the queries and everything else much simpler and more readable.

```
class PunchLog(models.Model):
    ...
    is_in = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

It might make sense make a similar adjustment to the other log model as well.

**EDIT**

However, perhaps you want to review your entire model architecture. I think that both logs are similar enough to be the practically the same thing. Also, I think it is conceptually not correct to make two log entries in certain not obvious conditions, when only one event occurs. With a simpler architecture, the queries become trivial.

How about combining your logs?

```
class LogEntry(models.Model):
   local_user = models.ForeignKey(...)
   created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   is_in = models.BooleanField(...)
   is_biometric = models.BooleanField(...)
```

Comment: Could you help me out with how the final query will look like ?
What you have suggested is infact a great addition which will help preventing errors if someone adds a new log in between.
What about adding a new table with punch_in and punch_out as foreign keys referancing to punch log table ?

Comment: I added some more suggestions about your model. Keep it simple.

Comment: I have made two seperate logs because the punch logs are using staff id, and biometrics device use its own local users list, this list get synced to the server and anytime local user gets linked to a staff user, it will automatically create punch log entries for that specific local user. I have actually updated is_in column.

Comment: I understand the logic as far as that goes. I still think a simpler design is preferable.